# How to get values from model class if I have complex JSON Array?

Tags: java, android, json

I'm facing issue with inner jsonarray. Below I'm providing my JSON response and issues in step .Kindly review and provide me solution .
JSON Response:

```
{
        "Response": {
            "ResponseCode": 1,
            "ResponseText": "Success"
        },
        "Detail": [
            {
                "DateOfSlot": "08/31/2018",
                "AvailableTimeSlots": [
                    {
                        "TimeSlotId": 42,
                        "TimeOfSlot": "12:15 PM",
                        "TimeofSlotDateTime": "2018-08-31T12:15:00"
                    },
                    {
                        "TimeSlotId": 110,
                        "TimeOfSlot": "11:45 PM",
                        "TimeofSlotDateTime": "2018-08-31T23:45:00"
                    }
                ],
                "ScheduleId": 4203,
                "GetBlockedTimings": [
                    {
                        "DateOfSlot": "8/31/2018 12:00:00 AM",
                        "AvailableTimeSlots": null,
                        "ScheduleId": 0,
                        "GetBlockedTimings": null,
                        "BlockId": 1831,
                        "fkTimeId": 42,
                        "IsDeleted": false,
                        "fkScheduledId": 4203,
                        "utcDateOfSlot": "0001-01-01T00:00:00"
                    }
                ],
                "BlockId": 0,
                "fkTimeId": 0,
                "IsDeleted": false,
                "fkScheduledId": 0,
                "utcDateOfSlot": "2018-08-31T00:00:00Z"
            },
            {
                "DateOfSlot": "09/1/2018",
                "AvailableTimeSlots": [
                    {
                        "TimeSlotId": 112,
                        "TimeOfSlot": "12:00 AM",
                        "TimeofSlotDateTime": "2018-09-01T00:00:00"
                    },

                    {
                        "TimeSlotId": 110,
                        "TimeOfSlot": "11:45 PM",
                        "TimeofSlotDateTime": "2018-09-01T23:45:00"
                    }
                ],
                "ScheduleId": 4204,
                "GetBlockedTimings": null,
                "BlockId": 0,
                "fkTimeId": 0,
                "IsDeleted": false,
                "fkScheduledId": 0,
                "utcDateOfSlot": "2018-08-31T00:00:00Z"
            },
            {
                "DateOfSlot": "09/2/2018",
                "AvailableTimeSlots": [
                    {
                        "TimeSlotId": 112,
                        "TimeOfSlot": "12:00 AM",
                        "TimeofSlotDateTime": "2018-09-02T00:00:00"
                    },

                    {
                        "TimeSlotId": 110,
                        "TimeOfSlot": "11:45 PM",
                        "TimeofSlotDateTime": "2018-09-02T23:45:00"
                    }
                ],
                "ScheduleId": 4205,
                "GetBlockedTimings": null,
                "BlockId": 0,
                "fkTimeId": 0,
                "IsDeleted": false,
                "fkScheduledId": 0,
                "utcDateOfSlot": "2018-09-01T00:00:00Z"
            }
        ]
    }
```

1. On 1 screen I'm using 3 text view. In these text view, I have to show  "DateOfSlot" parameter value.
2. On the same screen, I have 3 lists, where I have to show data as per selected or clicked text view other will invisible.Like as first text view value is   `DateOfSlot": "08/31/2018` then I have to show only on JSONObject [0]  "AvailableTimeSlots" jsonarray's  `TimeOfSlot": "12:15 PM` values in list. and if  "GetBlockedTimings" jsonarray is not null then I have to change the text color of that value . for color change we have to compare  "fkTimeId" and   "TimeSlotId" . if both are equal then that row text should change (red color).

```html
 private void pastappointments() {


        final String requestBody = "'{\"UtcTimeOffset\":\"330\",\"DocId\":\"1079\"}'";

        Log.e(TAG, "Login :: " + requestBody);
        NetworkManager.getInstance(this).makeNetworkRequestForJSON(1, Request.Method.POST, Common.BASE_URL + "/PostDoctorGetDoctorSchedule", null, requestBody
                , null,
                new NetworkResponseListenerJSONObject() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataReceived(int requestCode, Object data) {

                        Log.e(TAG, "requestCode :: " + requestCode);
                        Log.e(TAG, "data :: " + data);
                        Log.e(TAG, "Response : " + data.toString());

                        try {

                            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(data.toString());
                            JSONObject ResponseJsonObject1 = jsonObject.getJSONObject("Response");
                            int ResponseCode = ResponseJsonObject1.getInt("ResponseCode");
                            String ResponseText = ResponseJsonObject1.getString("ResponseText");

                            int j = 0;
                            AvailableTimeSlots available_slot = null;
                            if (ResponseCode == 1) {
                                JSONArray detailsJsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("Detail");

//                                for (int i = 0; i < detailsJsonArray.length(); i++)
//                                {

                                JSONObject detailOneObject = detailsJsonArray.getJSONObject(0);

                                String date_one = detailOneObject.getString("DateOfSlot");
                                rb_today.setText(date_one);
                                String BlockId = detailOneObject.getString("BlockId");
                                String fkTimeId = detailOneObject.getString("fkTimeId");
                                Boolean IsDeleted = detailOneObject.getBoolean("IsDeleted");
                                int fkScheduledId = detailOneObject.getInt("fkScheduledId");
                                String utcDateOfSlot = detailOneObject.getString("utcDateOfSlot");
                                String ScheduleId = detailOneObject.getString("ScheduleId");
                                slot = new PostDoctorGetDoctorSchedule();
                                slot.setDateOfSlot(date_one);
                                slot.setBlockId(BlockId);
                                slot.setScheduleId(ScheduleId);
                                slot.setFkTimeId(fkTimeId);
                                slot.setIsDeleted(IsDeleted);
                                slot.setFkScheduledId(fkScheduledId);
                                slot.setUtcDateOfSlot(utcDateOfSlot);
                                //slot.AvailableTimeSlots = new ArrayList<>();
                                JSONArray AvailableTimeSlots = detailOneObject.getJSONArray("AvailableTimeSlots");
                                available_slot = null;
                                for (j = 0; j < AvailableTimeSlots.length(); j++) {
                                    // JSONObject AvailableTimeSlots_detailOneObject = detailsJsonArray.getJSONObject(0);
                                    JSONObject leagueData = AvailableTimeSlots.getJSONObject(j);

                                    String TimeSlotId = leagueData.getString("TimeSlotId");
                                    String TimeOfSlot = leagueData.getString("TimeOfSlot");
                                    String TimeofSlotDateTime = leagueData.getString("TimeofSlotDateTime");

                                    available_slot = new AvailableTimeSlots();
                                    available_slot.timeSlotId = Integer.parseInt(TimeSlotId);
                                    available_slot.timeOfSlot = TimeOfSlot;
                                    available_slot.timeofSlotDateTime = TimeofSlotDateTime;
                                    //slot.AvailableTimeSlots.add(available_slot);
                                    availableTimeSlotses.add(available_slot);
                                    slot.setAvailableTimeSlots(availableTimeSlotses);
                                    PostDoctorGetDoctorSchedulepojo.add(slot);
                                    pastAppointmentsAdapter = new PastAppointmentAdapter(MainActivity.this, PostDoctorGetDoctorSchedulepojo);
                                    rv_get_doctor_schedule.setAdapter(pastAppointmentsAdapter);

                                }
                                //slot.GetBlockedTimings = new ArrayList<GetBlockedTimings>();
                                JSONArray GetBlockedTimings = detailOneObject.getJSONArray("GetBlockedTimings");

//                                if (GetBlockedTimings.length() > 0 || GetBlockedTimings != null)
//                                {
                                for (int k = 0; k < GetBlockedTimings.length(); k++) {
                                    JSONObject leagueData_block = GetBlockedTimings.getJSONObject(k);
                                    String DateOfSlot = leagueData_block.getString("DateOfSlot");
                                    String AvailableTimeSlots_block = leagueData_block.getString("AvailableTimeSlots");
                                    int ScheduleId_block = leagueData_block.getInt("ScheduleId");
                                    int BlockId_block = leagueData_block.getInt("BlockId");
                                    int fkTimeId_block = leagueData_block.getInt("fkTimeId");
                                    int fkScheduledId_block = leagueData_block.getInt("fkScheduledId");
                                    String GetBlockedTimings_block = leagueData_block.getString("GetBlockedTimings");
                                    String utcDateOfSlot_block = leagueData_block.getString("utcDateOfSlot");
                                    Boolean IsDeleted_block = leagueData_block.getBoolean("IsDeleted");

                                    getblock_slot = new GetBlockedTimings();
                                    getblock_slot.setBlockId(BlockId_block);
                                    getblock_slot.setFkTimeId(fkTimeId_block);
                                    getblock_slot.setFkScheduledId(fkScheduledId_block);
                                   //  Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"timeid"+getblock_slot.getFkTimeId(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                }
                                if (GetBlockedTimings.length() > 0 || GetBlockedTimings != null) {

                                    getBlockedTimings.add(getblock_slot);
                                    slot.setGetBlockedTimings(getBlockedTimings);
                                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"timeid"+slot.getGetBlockedTimings(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    PostDoctorGetDoctorSchedulepojo.add(slot);
                                }
                                else
                                    {
                                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Nothing is here", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }


                            }


                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onDataFailed(int requestCode, VolleyError error) {

                        Log.e(TAG, "requestCode :: " + requestCode);
                        Log.e(TAG, "data :: " + error);

                        String json = null;
                        NetworkResponse response = error.networkResponse;
                        if (response != null && response.data != null) {
                            switch (response.statusCode) {
                                case 400:
                                    json = new String(response.data);
                                    json = trimMessage(json, "error_description");
                                    if (json != null) displayMessage(json);
                                    break;
                            }
                            //Additional cases
                        }
                    }

                });
    }
```

My Adapter class code

```html
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final PastAppointmentsViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        final PostDoctorGetDoctorSchedule c = PostDoctorGetDoctorSchedule.get(position);
        try{
          timeofslot=c.AvailableTimeSlots.get(position).getTimeOfSlot();


            holder.tv_past_appointmentname.setText(timeofslot);
        }
        catch (NullPointerException | IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }



       try{
           fk_id = c.GetBlockedTimings.get(position).getFkTimeId();
           value_block=fk_id;
           Log.e("DateofSlot11122", String.valueOf(fk_id));
       }
       catch (NullPointerException | IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }

String fk_value= String.valueOf(fk_id);

       if(timeofslot==fk_value){
           holder.tv_past_appointmentname.setTextColor(Color.RED);
       }

      holder.ll_row_item_get_doctor_schedule.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @SuppressLint("LongLogTag")
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                holder.btn_block1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        });
        holder.btn_block1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                holder.tv_past_appointmentname.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ff0000"));



                final Dialog lDialog = new Dialog(context);
                lDialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
                lDialog.setCancelable(false);
                lDialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
                lDialog.getWindow().setDimAmount(.7f);
                lDialog.getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_BLUR_BEHIND);
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP_MR1) {
                    lDialog.getWindow().setElevation(4);
                }

                lDialog.setContentView(R.layout.popup_no_yes);
                TextView tv_titiel = (TextView) lDialog.findViewById(R.id.tv_titiel);
                TextView textMsg = (TextView) lDialog.findViewById(R.id.popup_msgs);
                Button btnno = (Button) lDialog.findViewById(R.id.popup_no_btn);
                Button btnyes = (Button) lDialog.findViewById(R.id.popup_yes_btn);
                btnno.setTransformationMethod(null);
                btnyes.setTransformationMethod(null);
                tv_titiel.setText("Schedule");
                textMsg.setText("Are you sure you want to block this slot?");
                btnno.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        lDialog.dismiss();
                        holder.tv_past_appointmentname.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
                    }
                });
                btnyes.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {

                        holder.tv_past_appointmentname.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ff0000"));
                        timeslot_id_value=c.AvailableTimeSlots.get(position).getTimeSlotId();
                        fkscheduleid=c.getScheduleId();
                        DateofSlot=c.getDateOfSlot();
                        Toast.makeText(context,"click_value"+timeslot_id_value + " " + fkscheduleid,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                        slotBlockingApi();
                        lDialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });
                lDialog.show();

            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem you are facing? At which step, because you haven't really shared any specific problem rather your requirement.

Comment: I want this, my requirement is my issue .I don't know how i can complete this.  It's showing all appointment array values on first screen but i want show only first jsonobject 0 index value  "AvailableTimeSlots in first list . On click 2nd textview then show 1 index "AvailableTimeSlotson 2nd list ....

Comment: @Hi Ankur, above i have given my code plz read it and provide me solution

Answer (score 0):

[this link](https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-do-convert-java-object-to-from-json-format-gson-api/) could help us, i think )

---

OK,

1.our model classes could be like:

```
public class SlotInfo {
    public String dateOfSlot;
    public ArrayList<AvailableTimeSlot> availableTimeSlots;
    public long scheduleId;
    public ArrayList<GetBlockedTiming> getBlockedTimings;

    public long blockId;
    public long fkTimeId;
    public boolean isDeleted;
    public long fkScheduledId;
    public long utcDateOfSlot;
}

public class AvailableTimeSlot {
    public long timeSlotId;
    public String timeOfSlot;
    public String timeofSlotDateTime;
}

public class GetBlockedTiming {
    public String dateOfSlot;
    public ArrayList<AvailableTimeSlot> availableTimeSlots;
    public ArrayList<GetBlockedTiming> getBlockedTimings;
    public long blockId;
    public long fkTimeId;
    public boolean isDeleted;
    public long fkScheduledId;
    public long utcDateOfSlot;
}
```

2. and we should

   ```
   ArrayList<SlotInfo> slotInfos = new ArrayList<>();
   try {
       JSONObject jSlots = new JSONObject("Your JSON String");
       JSONArray arrDetail = jSlots.getJSONArray("Detail");

       for(int i = 0; i < arrDetail.length(); i++) {

           JSONObject jSlot = arrDetail.getJSONObject(i);

           SlotInfo slotInfo = new SlotInfo();

           slotInfo.blockId = jSlot.getLong("blockId");
           slotInfo.dateOfSlot = jSlot.getString("dateOfSlot");
           slotInfo.fkScheduledId = jSlot.getLong("fkScheduledId");
           slotInfo.fkTimeId = jSlot.getLong("fkTimeId");
           // so set all top level data ...

           // then availableTimeSlots
           slotInfo.availableTimeSlots = new ArrayList<>();
           JSONArray arrAvailableTimeSlots = jSlots.getJSONArray("AvailableTimeSlots");
           for(int j = 0; j < arrAvailableTimeSlots.length(); j++) {
               JSONObject jAvailableTimeSlot = arrAvailableTimeSlots.getJSONObject(j);

               AvailableTimeSlot availableTimeSlot = new AvailableTimeSlot();
               availableTimeSlot.timeOfSlot = jAvailableTimeSlot.getString("timeOfSlot");
               // so set all data ...

               // and add it to
               slotInfo.availableTimeSlots.add(availableTimeSlot);
           }

           // then GetBlockedTimings
           slotInfo.getBlockedTimings = new ArrayList<>();
           JSONArray arrGetBlockedTimings = jSlots.getJSONArray("GetBlockedTimings");
           for(int k = 0; k < arrGetBlockedTimings.length(); k++) {
               JSONObject jGetBlockedTiming = arrAvailableTimeSlots.getJSONObject(k);

               GetBlockedTiming getBlockedTiming = new GetBlockedTiming();
               getBlockedTiming.blockId = jGetBlockedTiming.getLong("blockId");
               // so set all data ...

               // and add it to
               slotInfo.getBlockedTimings.add(getBlockedTiming);

           }

           slotInfos.add(slotInfo);
       }

   } catch (JSONException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
   }
   ```

---

3. how can we get the "DateOfSlot" values and show them in  the test boxes ?

suppose we define the text views in the class level:

```
    TextView tvDateOfSlot1;
    TextView tvDateOfSlot2;
    TextView tvDateOfSlot3;
```

so we can set them in the onCreateView like:

```
    tvDateOfSlot1  = findViewById(R.id.tv_dateOfSlot1);
    tvDateOfSlot2  = findViewById(R.id.tv_dateOfSlot2);
    tvDateOfSlot3  = findViewById(R.id.tv_dateOfSlot3);
```

then, after the initialization of the "slotInfos" we can set the textView values like:

```
   tvDateOfSlot1.setText(slotInfos[0].dateOfSlot);
   tvDateOfSlot2.setText(slotInfos[1].dateOfSlot);
   tvDateOfSlot3.setText(slotInfos[2].dateOfSlot);
```

Good luck )

---

Good luck )

Comment: I have checked this link , they are using GSON .but I don't want to follow this .

Comment: yes , I want firstly save all json response in model class then show values via adapter .

Comment: Is here someone who can help me?plz

Comment: Thanks @Hovanes . Let me try .

Comment: slotInfo.availableTimeSlots = new ArrayList<>(); what is availableTimeSlots here?

Comment: it is the array list of the model AvailableTimeSlot: 


                "AvailableTimeSlots": [
                    {
                        "TimeSlotId": 42,
                        "TimeOfSlot": "12:15 PM",
                        "TimeofSlotDateTime": "2018-08-31T12:15:00"
                    },
                    {
                        "TimeSlotId": 110,
                        "TimeOfSlot": "11:45 PM",
                        "TimeofSlotDateTime": "2018-08-31T23:45:00"
                    }
                ],

Comment: Stringdoc_name=c.getAvailableTimeSlots().get(position).getTimeOfSlot();//java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException:Index:0,Size:0erroronthislineinonBindViewHolder()inadapterholder.tv_past_appointmentname.setText(doc_name);@  Hovanes

Comment: How I'll show TimeOfSlot value in text .Please let me know

Comment: we should get the text view  we want by:
 TextView tv = findViewById(R.id.THE_TEXTVIEW_ID) and set the value:
 tv.setText(THE VALUE WE WANT);

Comment: I'm doing same thing in my adapter but not happening @Hovanes

Comment: please 1. define and set the textView property textView property in your YourViewHolder  class:

    class YourViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

        private TextView textView;

        public YourViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            view.setOnClickListener(this);
            textView = view.findViewById(R.id.txt_time_of_slot);
            ...
        }
        ...
}

and 2. 

public void onBindViewHolder(YourViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.textView.setText(YOUR VALUE);
        ...
}

Comment: @ Hovanes Thanks for your support ,Your efforts .but I'm also doing same thing but not working .

Comment: please provide your adapter class code snippet, it's so hard to suppose what goes there )

Comment: Plz tell me how i can share my code , Bcoz it's size is large .   :(

Comment: please find the code snipped appended to the answer above )

Answer (score 0):

```
JsonObject mainObject = new JsonObject("Your JSON String");
JsonArray arr = mainObject.getJsonArray("Detail");

for(int i = 0; i < arr.lenght(); i++) {
    JsonObject dateOfSlotObj = arr.getJsonObject(i);
    String dateOfSlot = dateOfSlotObj.getString("DateOfSlot");//DateOfSlot field
    JsonArray availableSlotsArr = dateOfSlotObj.getJsonArray("AvailableTimeSlots");
    for(int j = 0; j < availableSlotsArr.lenght(); j++) {
        JsonObject availableSlotObj = availableSlotsArr[j];
        int timeSlotId = availableSlotObj.getInt("TimeSlotId");
        String timeOfSlot= availableSlotObj.getString("TimeOfSlot");
        String timeofSlotDateTime= availableSlotObj.getString("TimeofSlotDateTime");
    }
}
```

To check if GetBlockedTimings not null you can check with next line of code

```
    if(!dateOfSlotObj.isNull("GetBlockedTimings")){
          //extract array and do something
    }
```

Comment: Save all parsed data in array or somewhere else, then you can check values of this data and change text colors or something else

Comment: for(int j = 0; j < availableSlotsArr.lenght(); j++) {
        JsonObject availableSlotObj = availableSlotsArr[j];
        int timeSlotId = availableSlotObj.getInt("TimeSlotId");
        String timeOfSlot= availableSlotObj.getString("TimeOfSlot");
        String timeofSlotDateTime= availableSlotObj.getString("TimeofSlotDateTime");
    }     I have to save this data in model class and show show in adapter class .How I can do this?

Comment: you could edit your question in the top and append it, please

Comment: @SashaSheremeta your first code block has low readability and it makes it hard for reusing it in the future. can you make it more readable so it would have a better impact on other developers? here is something you can do: add some blank lines and separate different parts of your code and comment on that part so it is easier to understand what you are doing. thank you :)